# Can you define what a reference should say in clear text?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, apa-style

When you create a reference list (with the command `\bibliography{x}`), using the `apacite` package, is there any way to hijack the list, so of speak, and define what individual entries should say in clear text?

For example, if I want to refer to a painting, and I'm using [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/) as my database for papers, it might get a little tricky to get everything to show up right. Here, instead of trying to hack the style and BibTeX files, it would be much more convenient to just spell out in clear text exactly what the reference should say.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, as I'm not sure if it's what you're after: Is it an option to edit the `.bbl` file that is generated by BibTeX? It's not a good way, as that file is regenerated on each BibTeX run, hence you would have to do the change only after the final run of BibTeX.

Comment: Exactly. That's one of the problems. In my case, the file gets regenerated by Mendeley so I would have to move it to another location and modify it right before I'm done with my text. However, I'm still not sure if I would be able to modify the file in such a way so that it looked the way I wanted.

Comment: @Speldosa I don't follow the use of both `natbib` and `biblatex-apa`. Are you open to a `biblatex`-only solution? Bibliography drivers can be overridden...

Comment: @Audrey No, you're completely right. I don't know why I use both either. I'll edit the question to only include `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: Given the flexibility of `biblatex` it seems to me that you shouldn't need to do this. Do you have a specific example of a particular entry type that you are having difficulty with? (i.e. a bit more detail on your painting example and what Mendelay gives you in the `.bib` file.)

Comment: @Speldosa OK. I had guessed that and came up with the solution below, but I'm in agreement with Alan's comment.

Comment: @misc{Allen2010,
author = {Baker, Allen},
booktitle = {The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy},
doi = {10.1111/1467-9973.00225},
edition = {Spring},
file = {:Users/Martin/Dropbox/Dokument/Mendeley/The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy/Baker/Baker - 2010 - Simplicity.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0026-1068},
month = jan,
number = {1\&2},
title = {{Simplicity}},
url = {http://plato.stanford.edu/archives/spr2010/entries/simplicity/},
volume = {33},
year = {2010}
}

Comment: @Alan This shows up as: "Baker, A. (2010, January). Simplicity (Spring ed., Vol. 33) (No. 1&2). Available from http://plato.stanford .edu/archives/spr2010/entries/simplicity/". Half of these data I haven't even punched in in Mendeley and I can't find any fields to edit it (for example the month entry). Maybe I could change it, with some time, but I have a deadline and I rather use my brain resources for writing on my actual thesis rather than to try to get LaTeX to do what I want without "cheating". (Note that this is BibTeX not BibLaTeX, see my comment on Audrey's answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `biblatex`, you can override the bibliography drivers as done below. However I probably wouldn't handle the problem this way. The bibliography drivers save you from having to worry about too much format, line breaking, spacing and punctuation. They also ensure entries of the same type are set consistently and can handle bibliographic data in a flexible manner. Considering this, I'd probably reformulate this question or ask a new question providing an example with the problematic entries and the output you're wanting to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

% Identify bib entries that must be manually set
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifthenelse{\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{7.01:1}%
              \OR\iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{7.01:2}}
    {\def\abx@field@entrytype{customa}}
    {}}
\makeatother

% Provide text for manual entries
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{customa}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{7.01:1}
    {Entry 7.01:1 --- Herbst-Damm and Kulik. \mkbibemph{Volunteer Support...}}
    {}%
  \iffieldequalstr{entrykey}{7.01:2}
    {Entry 7.01:2 --- Gilbert et al. \mkbibemph{Effects of...}}
    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{7.01:1,
  AUTHOR         = {K. L. Herbst-Damm and J. A. Kulik},
  TITLE          = {Volunteer Support, Marital Status, and the Survival Times of Terminally Ill Patients},
  JOURNALTITLE   = {Health Psychology},
  VOLUME         = {24},
  PAGES          = {225--229},
  YEAR           = {2005},
  DOI            = {10.1037/0278-6133.24.2.225},
  URL            = {http://some.url}
}
@ARTICLE{7.01:2,
  AUTHOR         = {D. G. Gilbert and J. F. McClernon and N. E. Rabinovich and C. Sugai and L. C. Plath and G. Asgaard and D. Dickinson and N. Botros},
  TITLE          = {Effects of Quitting Smoking and {EEG} Activation and Attention Last for More Than 31 Days and are More Severe With Stress, Depedence, {DRD2 A1} Allele, and Depressive Traits},
  JOURNALTITLE   = {Nicotine and Tobacco Research},
  VOLUME         = {6},
  PAGES          = {249--267},
  YEAR           = {2004},
  DOI            = {10.1080/14622200410001676305}
}
@ARTICLE{7.01:3a,
  AUTHOR         = {T. J. Sillick and N. S. Schutte},
  TITLE          = {Emotional Intelligence and Self-esteem Mediate Between Perceived Early Parental Love and Adult Happiness.},
  JOURNALTITLE   = {E-Journal of Applied Psychology},
  VOLUME         = {2},
  NUMBER         = {2},
  PAGES          = {38--48},
  YEAR           = {2006},
  URL            = {http://ojs.lib.swin.edu.au/index.php/ejap}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. Does anyone know of a thread which talkes about how you can use `BibLaTeX-apa` in conjunction with Mendeley? As I understand it, Mendeley only create files that can be used with BibTeX (that's why I changed my description above to be about `apacite` rather than `BibLaTeX-apa`).

Comment: @Speldosa So I guess you meant `apacite` and not `biblatex-apa` all along? `biblatex` can, among other things, read data from a `bib` file. Doesn't Mendeley generate a `bib` file for you?

Comment: Yes, Mendeley generates a bib-file. However, I can't get it to work with BibLaTeX-apa and I just inferred that this was because of the file I tried to use it with. To find documentation about these things in any other language than geek seems to be really hard :)

Comment: @Speldosa It'll be hard for anyone to help troubleshoot without details on the error messages you received. For simplicity try adapting the above code again, but this time replace lines 2-6 with `\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}`. Omit the `filecontents` environment and in `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` replace `\jobname` with the name of your `bib` file.

Comment: No matter how I do, I get the error message `/Tmp.aux:6: Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \APACbibcite
                {Moody2003}{\citeauthoryear {Moody}{Moody}{{\APACyear {2003}}}}` Moody2003 is a reference I'm using in other papers I'm writing, I haven't even tried to invoke it here. I'm taking this to a regular forum to get it troubleshot.

Comment: Ok, I solved that problem (I had to throw away earlier generated files such as .aux and let them regenerate). I'll check out your solution now. It looks great :)

Comment: @Speldosa Good to hear. Auxillary files - aux, bbl, bcf, blg - should be deleted before compiling major changes to your bibliography data or style. Sorry you had to learn that the hard way. `biblatex` defines a number of entry types that might be more appropriate for your references - e.g. `@artwork`, `@image`, etc. They are handled like `@misc`, but new drivers can be defined to generate the output you want. All we'd need to help you define those would be the `bib` file entries (like the one you gave above) and your "clear text" of the bibliography.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to do it "the real way" and use this clear text solution if nothigh else works. I'll probably post again :)